# How to check a geckodriver is running on a remote machine?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am writing automatic tests using Selenium / Maven / testng.

Tests are performed on a virtual machine Windows Server 2016 Standard.

I would like to check if the tasklist is running geckodriver. I do:

```
    String line;
String pidInfo ="";

Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");

BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    pidInfo+=line; 
}

input.close();

if(pidInfo.contains("geckodriver.exe"))
{
    // do what you want
}
```

After running the tests, the code executes them on the local computer.

How to perform such a check on a Virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully defined.
A virtual machine has a operating system. And this is missing in your query.

But to give you a answer which is probably fitting, usually VMs are Linux based.

you can execute on Windows on command line manually to get the correct path

`where tasklist`

this will retrun you the right path to the command. If this is missing search for the command and check why it is missing on the PATH-variable (not  a standard windows installation)

in my case it was

`C:\Windows\System32\tasklist.exe`

you execute on linux

`ps aux | grep geckodriver`

on MAC you can try also

`ps aux | grep geckodriver`

but maybe this is better

`ps -jef | grep geckodriver`

to get the correct full path to ps command on linux and MAC execute

`which ps`

hope it helps

**Other point:**

You should not use "\" path separators manually. I always would use

`File.separator` which will give you the correct OS-path character

Comment: Virtual machine has a Windows Server 2016 Standard

Comment: please update your question with the error you get. Also please share the error of executing tasklist manually

Comment: params passed in the original post include system32 and windir, which suggests that this is for Windows. Clarification is always good though.

Comment: @KamilBolc I have updated my answer, with the suggestion of adickinson. Hope it helps more

Comment: Running tests does not cause an error.

The problem is that I have a list of tasks from the local computer and not from the Virtual machine.

Comment: @KamilBolc, are you working with remote selenium tests?

Comment: yes i use 

 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("xxxxxx");

Comment: what is a completely different story! You are aware, that your code is always executed on the selenium master? and you do a remote control of the browser on the windows server?

Comment: Yes, and is there any solution this task ?